# How can I explicitly show line breaks as "\n" inside a HTML <textarea> tag?

Tags: javascript, html, string, encoding, character-encoding

I am writing a simple webapp that turns plain text into python code.

Example:
this is my plain text ----> print("this is my plain text")

the plain text is stored on a regular textarea. The output text is stored on a disabled textarea.

Problem:
HTML parses \n automatically and I haven't found a good way of keeping \n inside the output textarea. This is a problem since copying the content inside the output textarea does not work properly.

Here is what I'm trying to do:

Input:
Foo
Bar

Output:
print("Foo\nBar")

---

Source Code:

```js
 function set(el, text) {
            while (el.firstChild) el.removeChild(el.firstChild);
            el.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text))
        }

        /* setupUpdater will be called once, on page load.
         */

        function setupUpdater() {
            var input = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0],
                output = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[1],
                timeout = null;

            function handleChange() {
                //string.replace(/[\n]/g, '\n')
                var inputText = input.value;
                set(output, "print(\"" + inputText + "\")");
                ("\n");
            }

            /* eventHandler is called on keyboard and mouse events.
               If there is a pending timeout, it cancels it.
               It sets a timeout to call handleChange in 0ms. */
            function eventHandler() {
                if (timeout) clearTimeout(timeout);
                timeout = setTimeout(handleChange, 0);
            }
            input.onkeydown = input.onkeyup = input.onclick = eventHandler;
        }
        setupUpdater();
        document.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0].focus();
```

```html
        <div class="grid-container">
            <textarea name="plainText" id="plainText" cols="40" rows="40" placeholder="Enter your plain text here"></textarea>
            <textarea name="plainText" id="plainText" cols="40" rows="40" readonly>print("")</textarea>
        </div>
```

I'll be happy to clarify anything that has been left unexplained by me but I do hope the question and what I'm trying to achieve is clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.replace` doesn't mutate the existing string - you need to use the resulting expression somehow, like concatenate it with the `print` screen you're creating.

To replace newlines with `\n`, search for newlines with `/\n/g` and replace with `\\n` (a literal backslash, followed by a literal `n`).

You should also replace `"`s with `\"`:

```
set(output, `print("${input.value.replace(/\n/g, '\\n').replace(/"/g, '\\"')}")`);
```

```js
function set(el, text) {
  while (el.firstChild) el.removeChild(el.firstChild);
  el.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text))
}

/* setupUpdater will be called once, on page load.
 */

function setupUpdater() {
  var input = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0],
    output = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[1],
    timeout = null;

  function handleChange() {
    set(output, `print("${input.value.replace(/\n/g, '\\n').replace(/"/g, '\\"')}")`);
  }

  /* eventHandler is called on keyboard and mouse events.
     If there is a pending timeout, it cancels it.
     It sets a timeout to call handleChange in 0ms. */
  function eventHandler() {
    if (timeout) clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(handleChange, 0);
  }
  input.onkeydown = input.onkeyup = input.onclick = eventHandler;
}
setupUpdater();
document.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0].focus();
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <textarea name="plainText" id="plainText" cols="40" rows="40" placeholder="Enter your plain text here">foo"bar</textarea>
  <textarea name="plainText" id="plainText" cols="40" rows="40" readonly>print("")</textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Totally forgot about String.replace not mutating the initial string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the string replace method with a regex to match all \n like:

```
const output = inputText.replace(/\n/g, '\\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine. just replace

```
var inputText = input.value;
  with 
var inputText = input.value.split(' ').join('\\n');
```